# Actionbar stretch out tabs

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Is it possible to fill the actionbar fully with tabs?
Currently my tabs are stretched out on a normal phone but when I go to tablet it's very small.

I already found this :

```
private void setTabsMaxWidth() {
   DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
   int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
   final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   final View tabView = actionBar.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();
   final View tabContainerView = (View) tabView.getParent();
   final int tabPadding = tabContainerView.getPaddingLeft() + tabContainerView.getPaddingRight();
   final int tabs = actionBar.getTabCount();
   for(int i=0 ; i < tabs ; i++) {
      View tab = actionBar.getTabAt(i).getCustomView();
      TextView text1 = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
      text1.setMaxWidth(screenWidth/tabs-tabPadding-1);
  }
}
```

and combined with custom view on tab :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

But still not working

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let me tell you that this technique for implementing tabs (as a navigation mode for the ActionBar) has been deprecated. You should use a pager adapter instead which will play nicely with the ToolBar. There are official android samples with SlidingTabLayouts which show you how to implement this, [see this dev byte for some more info.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk)

Secondly, if you go down the SlidingTabsLayout route, in the createDefaultTabView() method, I added this to ensure my two tabs fill the screen width equally:

```
    //Set tabs to take up entire screen width
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        display.getSize(size);
    }
    else
    {
        size.set(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
    }
    textView.setWidth(size.x / 2);
```

A quick look at your code makes me think you should be setting the width of the text view, not the maxWidth. But I think your calculation is less legible so I'm not sure if it's wrong too.

Comment: Yea I was busy a while ago with an application but I will switch to SlidingTabLyout. Thanks.

Comment: Good stuff, best of luck :)